# Is a request for specific information about software error messages really off topic?

Tags: support, reopen-request

I asked for a comprehensive list of error and informational messages produced by Robocopy. I described my problem (a huge log file), my efforts to resolve it (numerous web searches and reading articles that looked relevant), and my requested solution (a comprehensive list).

The log file did not indicate a Robocopy version number, but the tag indicated Windows 10.

I've added some minor revisions to my question, but they're more for clarity.

Was the question closed by mistake?

[Is there a comprehensive list of Robocopy error and informational messages?](https://superuser.com/questions/1701769/is-there-a-comprehensive-list-of-robocopy-error-and-informational-messages?noredirect=1#comment2619688_1701769)

Closure explanation does not appear to apply in any way:

> Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research. Here are a few suggestions on how to properly ask this type of question.

Answer (score 3):

> I described my problem (a huge log file), my efforts to resolve it (numerous web searches and reading articles that looked relevant), and my requested solution (a comprehensive list).

I personally would consider the following question asking for a learning material.

> Does anyone have a link to a complete list of Robocopy error messages that would appear in a log file?

Which is the reason I would agree with the selected close reason. *I have never seen a question, asking for what is potentially a huge list, be well received in my decade at Super User.*

> Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers.

Comment: This sums up pretty concisely why I closed it. "Please find me a list of something on the internet" is essentially the same as "find me a book that..." and as such is the same as a learning material request.